# Assigning 'undefined' a value, how?

Tags: javascript, undefined

I was trying to assign a value to the items of an empty array, but I couldn't manage.
I used the Array constructor, and tried using both the `.map()` and the `for ... of`, but it didn't work.

```js
let chrom = new Array(4);
const randomN = () => Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
for (g of chrom) {
  g = randomN()
}
```

However, this solution worked

```js
let emptyArr = new Array(4);
const randomN = () => Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
for (i=0; i<chrom.length; i++) {
  chrom[i] = randomN()
}
```

Somehow it seems like only specifying the indexes does the trick.
does anybody know why this happens? what should I read? I tried looking in the documentation, but I couldn't see anything there.

Comment: for...of is used to integrate over object keys.

Comment: `let chrom = Array.from({ length: 4 }, _ => Math.floor(Math.random() * 2));`. The local variable `g` in the `for ... of` loop is a copy of the array element, similar to `for (i = 0; i < chrom.length; i++) { let g = chrom[i]; g = randomN(); }`, which also wouldn't work.

Comment: @Fritzdultimate this isn't `for ... in`, and there is no "integrating over object keys". You potentially meant "iterate".

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is that in your first solution, `g` is going to be a local variable (a copy) instead of a reference to the actual value in the `chrom` array.

For example:

```js
let nums = [1, 2, 3]

for (let num of nums) {
  num = 1 // num in this case is a totally different variable
}

console.log(nums) // will still output [1, 2, 3]
```

[Here is a good article explaining the difference between value vs reference in Javascript.](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0)

Comment: Ohh, so it's basically the copy of the array what I'm modifying. I feel I was quite off here. 
Thanks, kibe.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `for...of` loop does not work since `g` is only a variable that holds the value of the element of the array at the current index; modifying it does not modify the array.

`Array#map` skips all empty slots, like those created by `Array(size)` or `new Array(size)`. An array literal with an empty slot looks like this: `[,]`. You can `fill` the array before mapping or use spread syntax.

```
chrom.fill().map(randomN);
//or
[...chrom].map(randomN);
```

The standard index-based `for` loop uses the `length` of the array, which includes empty slots and sets elements using the index, so it has the desired effect.